# How do I compute the sum of the outer products of all columns of a matrix in MATLAB without loops?

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization

I tried to make the title say it all.

I have a matrix and I need to computer the sum of the outer products of combinations of columns. I know how to do it with for-loops. But, is there a vectorized way to do it?

```
testData = rand(x);   
answer = zeros(x);
for i=1:x
  for j=1:x
    answer = answer + testData(:,i)'*testData(:,j);
  end
end
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [fast outer product in Matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8806064/fast-outer-product-in-matlab)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in this question [Fast Outer Product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8806064/fast-outer-product-in-matlab)

```
answer = testData.'*testData;
```

N.B. This gives the sum of the outer product of the **rows**.