# How to compute the sum of squares of outer products of two matrices minus a common matrix in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix-multiplication

Suppose there are three n * n matrices `X`, `Y`, `S`. How to fast compute the the following  **scalars** `b`

```
for i = 1:n
  b = b  + sum(sum((X(i,:)' * Y(i,:) - S).^2));
end
```

The computation cost is O(n^3). There exists a [fast way to compute the outer product of two matrices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8806064/how-to-compute-a-fast-outerproduct-between-two-matrices-in-matlab). Specifically, the **matrix** `C`

```
for i = 1:n
  C = C + X(i,:)' * Y(i,:);
end
```

can be calculated without for loop `C = A.'*B` which is only O(n^2). Is there exists a faster way to compute `b`?

Comment: did you mean `X(i,:)'*Y(i,:)` ? otherwise there is no mention of `Y`

Comment: yes, thanks for pointing out the error. I have corrected it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
X2 = X.^2;
Y2 = Y.^2;
S2 = S.^2;
b = sum(sum(X2.' * Y2 - 2 * (X.' * Y ) .* S + n * S2));
```

Given your example

```
b=0;
for i = 1:n
   b = b  + sum(sum((X(i,:).' * Y(i,:) - S).^2));
end
```

We can first bring the summation out of the loop:

```
b=0;
for i = 1:n
  b = b  + (X(i,:).' * Y(i,:) - S).^2;
end
b=sum(b(:))
```

Knowing that we can write `(a - b)^2` as `a^2 - 2*a*b + b^2`

```
b=0;
for i = 1:n
  b = b  + (X(i,:).' * Y(i,:)).^2 - 2.* (X(i,:).' * Y(i,:)) .*S + S.^2;
end
b=sum(b(:))
```

And we know that `(a * b) ^ 2` is the same as `a^2 * b^2`:

```
X2 = X.^2;
Y2 = Y.^2;
S2 = S.^2;
b=0;
for i = 1:n
  b = b  + (X2(i,:).' * Y2(i,:)) - 2.* (X(i,:).' * Y(i,:)) .*S + S2;
end
b=sum(b(:))
```

Now we can compute each term separately:

```
 b = sum(sum(X2.' * Y2 - 2 * (X.' * Y ) .* S + n * S2));
```

Here is the result of a test in Octave that compares my method and two other methods provided by @AndrasDeak and the original loop based solution for inputs of size `500*500`:

```
===rahnema1 (B)===
Elapsed time is 0.0984299 seconds.

===Andras Deak (B2)===
Elapsed time is 7.86407 seconds.

===Andras Deak (B3)===
Elapsed time is 2.99158 seconds.

===Loop solution===
Elapsed time is 2.20357 seconds


n=500;
X= rand(n);
Y= rand(n);
S= rand(n);

disp('===rahnema1 (B)===')
tic
    X2 = X.^2;
    Y2 = Y.^2;
    S2 = S.^2;
    b=sum(sum(X2.' * Y2 - 2 * (X.' * Y ) .* S + n * S2));
toc
disp('===Andras Deak (B2)===')
tic
    b2 = sum(reshape((permute(reshape(X, [n, 1, n]).*Y, [3,2,1]) - S).^2, 1, []));
toc
disp('===Andras Deak (B3)===')
tic
    b3 = sum(reshape((reshape(X, [n, 1, n]).*Y - reshape(S.', [1, n, n])).^2, 1, []));
toc
tic
    b=0;
    for i = 1:n
      b = b  + sum(sum((X(i,:)' * Y(i,:) - S).^2));
    end
toc
```

Comment: Very nice! -- I guess `sum(reshape(...))` is more expensive than `sum(sum(...))`? Is this because of the overhead in the `reshape` function? -- To avoid the double sum, in Octave you can do `sum((...)(:))`, and in MATLAB R2018b you can now do `sum(...,'all')`, which both are quite a bit more elegant than the double sum, and *should* be faster.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know exactly which of sum-reshape or sum-sum performs better. Here I used sum-sum to reflect the original code and may be more readable.  `sum((...)(:))` may complicate readability and `sum(...,'all')` uses the ugly string parameter passing. Comparing them  I think the difference in speed in the current problem is neglectible. May we need a more elegant function/operator?

Comment: The double sum requires an intermediate array, so in principle it does more work. But yes, I'm sure it's not a measurable difference in this case. I agree with your readability comments. A new operator would be awesome. Something like `sumall=@(x)sum(x(:))`. But that does imply 20 or so new operators (`meanall`, `stdall`, `maxall`, etc. etc.), you can't do one and not all the others. :)

Answer (score 3):

You probably can't spare time complexity, but you can make use of vectorization to get rid of the loop and make use of low-level code and caching as much as possible. Whether it's actually faster depends on your dimensions, so you need to do some timing tests to see if this is worth it:

```
% dummy data
n = 3;
X = rand(n);
Y = rand(n);
S = rand(n);

% vectorize
b2 = sum(reshape((permute(reshape(X, [n, 1, n]).*Y, [3,2,1]) - S).^2, 1, []));

% check
b - b2 % close to machine epsilon i.e. zero
```

What happens is that we insert a new singleton dimension in one of the arrays, ending up with an array of size `[n, 1, n]` against one with `[n, n]`, the latter being implicitly the same as `[n, n, 1]`. The overlapping first index corresponds to the `i` in your loop, the remaining two indices correspond to the matrix indices of the dyadic product you have for each `i`. Then we permute the indices in order to put the "`i`" index last, so that we can again broadcast the result with `S` of (implicit) size `[n, n, 1]`. What we then have is a matrix of size `[n, n, n]` where the first two indices are matrix indices in your original and the last one corresponds to `i`. We then just have to take the square and sum each term (instead of summing twice I reshaped the array to a row and summed once).

A slight variation of the above transposes `S` instead of the 3d array which might be faster (again, you should time it):

```
b3 = sum(reshape((reshape(X, [n, 1, n]).*Y - reshape(S.', [1, n, n])).^2, 1, []));
```

In terms of performance, `reshape` is free (it only reinterprets data, it doesn't copy) but `permute`/transpose will often lead to a perforance hit when data gets copied.